# Digital spanish dictionary to build a spellchecker

Tags: spanish, dictionary

I come to ask if you know about **some Spanish "dictionary" in any digital format**. In fact, I only need the words, but is not a problem if it has the meaning or translation of these words.

I have one with 80k words, but sadly that doesn't include all the variations of each word. Apps like LibreOffice, browsers, etc. have **spellcheckers**, and I have access to these files. But they use "Hunspell" format, divided in 2 files: one with 67k words, where each one have some markers that points to complex rules in the second file (called "affix file", but it has prefixes too) to create all the possible variations of that word.

For example, you can found the word *"poblar"* (to populate) like this:

```
poblar/IRDÀ
```

And this should indicate (I don't know exactly how) you can write *"re-poblar"* (re-populate), *"pobla-ndo"* (populating), *"poblar-on"* (they populate), etc.

So, a complete dictionary should have over one hundred thousands words.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to LL.SE. Is Wiktionary useful to you?

Comment: Hey, that's a cool idea! I'm glad to ask here. I let the [wiktionary spanish list of article names](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/eswiktionary/20210601/eswiktionary-20210601-all-titles.gz) here for googlers, and soon I'll add a parsed dictionary as answer for someone else looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to generated a list of all the spanish words (more than 1 million) file (although it's unsorted). I uploaded the .txt file and share the link in case someone else find it useful: [es_ES.txt](https://www.4shared.com/office/PL_9bh_diq/es_ES.html)